# In Typescript, how to make sure a variable matches a union-type case without rewriting its definition?

Tags: typescript

I have a union type like this:

```
type Union
    = { kind: UnionKind.One, x: string }
    | { kind: UnionKind.Two, y: number }

enum UnionKind { One, Two }
```

I want to make a constructor function that returns the first case.

```
function one(x: string): ReturnType {
    return { kind: UnionKind.One, x: x }
}
```

I can specify `ReturnType` either as (1) `{ kind: UnionKind.One, x: string }` or (2) `Union`.

(1) has a disadvantage that if I change the type in the future, the function would still be compiling successfully:

```
type Union
    = { kind: UnionKind.One, somethingElse: string }
    | { kind: UnionKind.Two, y: number }

// unfortunately, compiles :(
function one(x: string): { kind: UnionKind.One, x: string } {
    return { kind: UnionKind.One, x: x }
}
```

(2) has disadvantages that it loses an info I'm sure of & passes even if I return something of `UnionKind.Two`.

```
function one(x: string): Union {
    return { kind: UnionKind.One, x: x }
}
const foo = one("foo"); // foo is Union although I'm sure it's of UnionKind.One
console.log(foo.x);  // compilation error!

// passes although I want to return it something of `one`
function one(x: string): Union {
    return { kind: UnionKind.Two, y: x.toString() }
}
```

It's as if I want to say:

```
function one(x: string): returns conforms both to { kind: UnionKind.One, x: string } and Union {
    return { kind: UnionKind.One, x: x }
}
```

So, how to say that? Also, would be good if I didn't have to repeat the type definition of the case.

Note: I'm not using the word constructor in a special way, I mean it as a general function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{ kind: UnionKind.One } & Union`. Advantages:

```
// (1) You don't have to write the whole definition of the case
function one(x: string): { kind: UnionKind.One } & Union {
    return { kind: UnionKind.One, x: x }
}

// (2) It infers it's of the first case
const foo = one("foo");
console.log(foo.x); // Works! :)

// (3) If you return something not of `One`, it'll tell:
// happily doesn't compile :-)
function one(x: string): { kind: UnionKind.One } & Union {
    return { kind: UnionKind.Two, y: x.toString() }
}

// (4) If you change the union type in the future, you'll get a compilation error :)
type Union
    = { kind: UnionKind.One, somethingElse: string }
    | { kind: UnionKind.Two, y: number }

// Error! :)
function one(x: string): { kind: UnionKind.One } & Union {
    return { kind: UnionKind.One, x: x }
}
```

Again, note: You don't need to repeat the whole definition of the case!

Answer (score 1):

@HossamEl-Deen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52181609/2887218) works, and an intersection would be the best solution if you're using TypeScript 2.7 or below.  With the introduction of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) in TypeScript 2.8, however, there's another way which has some benefits over intersections.  Specifically, we use the [`Extract<T, U>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1391-L1394) type function provided in the standard library, defined as:

> ```
> /**
>  * Extract from T those types that are assignable to U
>  */
> type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
> ```

If `T` is a union type, then `Extract<T, U>` is just the pieces of that union which match `U`.  This is similar to `T & U`, but it allows the compiler to pluck out just the pieces of the union it needs.  The intersection doesn't get collapsed and ends up carrying around the types of the whole union.  Compare:

```
type ReturnTypeExtracted = Extract<Union, {kind: UnionKind. One}>
```

which evaluates as

```
{
    kind: UnionKind.One;
    x: string;
}
```

to

```
type ReturnTypeIntersection = { kind: UnionKind.One } & Union;
```

which evaluates as

```
({
    kind: UnionKind.One;
} & {
    kind: UnionKind.One;
    x: string;
}) | ({
    kind: UnionKind.One;
} & {
    kind: UnionKind.Two;
    y: number;
})
```

The latter is similar to the former, but it is still a union with the second constituent representing an impossible type.  I had at one time [suggested](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16386) that the compiler automatically collapse such types, but it's not likely to happen (there are some reasons why doing so would break some things and make everything slower).

So, for completeness, here's the suggested signature:

```
function one(x: string): Extract<Union, { kind: UnionKind.One }> {
    return { kind: UnionKind.One, x: x }
}
```

which gives you all the benefits and none of the disadvantages you need.

Again, the other answer is not incorrect at all.  But since TypeScript 2.8 came out I've been using this instead of intersections for the reasons I laid out above.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!